# java eclipse indigo problems executing executable jar (property file's in external folder in project)

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I create a executable jar with eclips indigo and use a bat file to run it.

when I execute I get alle kind of exceptions.
NoClassDefFoundError, Could not initialize class, ....

No matter what selection I make for creating the executable jar I have issue's.

I used to made executable jar's with the plugin Fatjar but it seems it doens' work anymoren (plugin) with indigo.

It seems the jar is not including the file's (logging and other prop file's) I include in a different folder in the project ?!

Any suggestions ... .

I get the following error-codes :

[image]

My structure is :

[image]

---

I tried using the Fatjar plugin and now I don't have a NoClassDefFoundError anymore but further down in my programm I get the next error :

[image]

Comment: it sounds like you're missing things from your classpath when you execute the JAR. Could you provide more details...

Comment: Even if I take the option "Copy required libraries into a sub-folder ..." I get exceptions. for example I use a property files for my logging and I get a FileNotFoundException for those property file's

Comment: More details.... What is in your batch file? Where are your property files? Does it run ok when launched from eclipse?

Comment: batfile =  @echo off
java -cp document.jar be.starter.Starter
pause | Eclipse - no problem |  Propertfiles are in a props folder in my project

Comment: Other comments appear on-target to me; my suggestion is to enlarge on how your app is set up and what errors you get.  What class(es) are not found?  do you have a manifest?  What libraries do you use, and how do you make them available at runtime?  What is your classpath and how do you specify it?  Do you use a bat file to run things, or are you trying to operate with just a double-click on a jar?  Are you on Windows?  There are multiple ways to set this up, so we can't say "do X" and fix it without knowing more about the situation.

Comment: regular project build up : different packages and classes. External jar (jodaTime, itext, junit, etc) in lib folder and loaded on the buildpath. Log files for logging in log folder. property files for logging etc in props folder. images for itext in image folder and so on. I get for example a java.io.FilenotfoundException : props\config.properties ... The system can not find you file. He tries to log that error and then I get Filenotfoundexception for the jdbc.propertie file. As stated above, I use a bat file with the executable jar and I'm on a windows machine (hence the bat file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this is the way to create a jar or runnable jar in eclipse

File -> Export-> Java ->Runnbale JAR file

Launch configuration : your Class containing the public static void main(String[] args)

Export destination : Target place

Library Handling:

Package required libraries into generated JAR

FINISH

Comment: I tried this, but I still get the errors when running the jar. I tried the other two options also and I get different errors. With Helios it also didn't work for me but I used Fat jar then to make the runnable jar's but for some reason this doesn't work in Indigo.

Comment: @Mitra   When I tried this my class didn't appear in the Launch Configuration list.  I can run it from within Eclipse.

Comment: I just need to know, that the application that you are putting inside the running jar, is it GUI or CLI ?

Comment: I assume console means Command line interface...then it wont work this way... u need to run it from command line